# How to display record from SQL Server in a textbox by stored procedure

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have table called `ItemsPricesTbl`:

```
ItemID
FirstUnitWholeSalePrice
FirstUnitShopperPrice
FirstUnitDemotionsPrice
FirstUnitPriceDefault
SecondUnitWholeSalePrice
SecondUnitShopperPrice
SecondUnitDemotionsPrice
SecondUnitPriceDefault
ThirdUnitWholeSalePrice
ThirdUnitShopperPrice
ThirdUnitDemotionsPrice
ThirdUnitPriceDefault
DefaultPrice
```

The stored procedure to get data is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Prices_Item_By_ID]
    @ItemID int
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT
        ItemID, FirstUnitWholeSalePrice, FirstUnitShopperPrice, 
        FirstUnitDemotionsPrice, FirstUnitPriceDefault,
        SecondUnitWholeSalePrice, SecondUnitShopperPrice,
        SecondUnitDemotionsPrice, SecondUnitPriceDefault,
        ThirdUnitWholeSalePrice, ThirdUnitShopperPrice,
        ThirdUnitDemotionsPrice, ThirdUnitPriceDefault,
        DefaultPrice 
    FROM
        ItemsPricesTbl 
    WHERE
        ItemID = @ItemID
END
```

In Vb I have a `DatabaseManager` class which has this code :

```
Private Function exeReader(ByRef cmd As SqlCommand, ByRef dr As SqlDataReader) As Integer
        Dim retval As Integer = -1
        cmd.Connection = Me.Connection
        Try
            If cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure Then
                Dim pr As New SqlParameter("@retval", SqlDbType.Int)
                pr.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pr)
            End If
            If cmd.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cmd.Connection.Open()
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure Then retval = cmd.Parameters("@retval").Value
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        Finally
            Me.close()
        End Try

        Return retval
    End Function
```

Also I have two classes: the data class and a business class .

Data class code :

```
Friend Sub Get_Prices_Item_By_ID(ByRef dt As DataTable, ByVal ItemID As Integer)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Get_Prices_Item_By_ID")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ItemID
    dm.fillTable(cmd, dt)
End Sub
```

And business class code :

```
Public Function Get_Prices_Item_By_ID(ByVal ItemID As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    p.Get_Prices_Item_By_ID(dt, ItemID)
    Return dt
End Function
```

What code do I have to put in search button?

I have tried this :

```
p.Get_Item_By_ID(FrmManage_Items.txtitemid.Text)
                FrmManage_Items.txtwholesaleone.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtcustomerone.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtsaleone.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.RadioButton4.Checked = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtwholesaletwo.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtcustomertwo.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtsaletwo.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.RadioButton5.Checked = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtwholesalethird.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtcustomerthird.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtsalethird.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.RadioButton6.Checked = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.TextBox20.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
```

But I didn't get the records - but the error I got in each textbox :

```
System.Data.DataRowCollection
```

Note: connection is in `app.config` file

Comment: How is it people can't use the VS debugger?

Comment: You haven't shared code of `Get_Item_By_Id` method. Can you also explain what your does? What other properties the data class have? Why method `exReader` integer value after stored procedure execution? Shouldn't it be returning the data from the data reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `ToString`'ing the `Rows` (all of them), not the data in a row. When you call `ToString` on a `DataRowCollection` it will give you "System.Data.DataRowCollection".

You need to pluck out the data at the row and column index that matches up to your textboxes. Your text box names do not match up to your column names, but making assumptions, do this:

```
FrmManage_Items.txtwholesaleone.Text = dt.Rows(0)("FirstUnitWholeSalePrice").ToString
FrmManage_Items.txtcustomerone.Text = dt.Rows(0)("FirstUnitShopperPrice").ToString
'etc....
```

Of course, you should make checks that you actually got at least one row back and none of the column values are null because you cannot call `ToString` if the column is `DBNull.Value`.

As an aside, there is no reason to pass your parameters `ByRef`. That's a whole different discussion, but it is wrong unless you actually intend to change the reference to the object (not its value or properties, its reference).

I would also recommend your command and connection be created inside the method so you can be sure to `Dispose()` them (along with the data adapter too) since they are disposable resources. Either that or you class needs to implement `IDisposable` and that is more complex.

Comment: `vb` uses **()** when accessing columns and rows, arrays... ;) you must primarly program using c#?

Comment: @Zaggler, thanks, I get tripped up all the time on the rare ocassions I have to venture away from c#.

Comment: Now Iam getting                Value of type system.data.datarowcollection connt be converted

Comment: You would not be getting that error from the code I provided, somewhere you are still using `dt.Rows` incorrectly.

Comment: Yes i have change the   

FrmManage_Items.txtwholesaleone.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FirstUnitWholeSalePrice"].ToString     

To                                     

FrmManage_Items.txtwholesaleone.Text = dt.Rows(0)("FirstUnitWholeSalePrice").ToString     

 Now i got There is no row at position 0.  

Thank you for help

Comment: Like I said, you have to make sure there is a row available. Maybe, `dt.Rows.Count`?

Comment: thanks 

i have checked i get 2 records 

'Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Count As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed.

Comment: You haven't shown any code that would throw that error. I have no idea where it is coming from.

Comment: This code 

FrmManage_Items.txtwholesaleone.Text = dt.Rows(0)("FirstUnitWholeSalePrice").ToString

Comment: That doesn't refer to Count. I'm sorry by I'm getting confused. If there is a row at index zero, and if that column value is not null, then that should work. Make sure you do those basic validations or else you will have errors.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote the wrong code of method

its not reader

it is :

```
Public Function fillTable(ByRef cmd As SqlCommand, ByRef dt As DataTable) As Integer
    Dim retval As Integer = -1
    dt = New DataTable
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = Me.Connection
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)

    If (Not dt Is Nothing) Then retval = dt.Rows.Count
    Return retval
End Function
```

And the code of button is :

```
p.Get_Prices_Item_By_ID(FrmManage_Items.txtitemid.Text)
                FrmManage_Items.txtwholesaleone.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtcustomerone.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtsaleone.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.RadioButton4.Checked = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtwholesaletwo.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtcustomertwo.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtsaletwo.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.RadioButton5.Checked = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtwholesalethird.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtcustomerthird.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.txtsalethird.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.RadioButton6.Checked = dt.Rows.ToString
                FrmManage_Items.TextBox20.Text = dt.Rows.ToString
```

i want to enter the id of item in txtitemid.text

and it will search for this id and return back the rest of record if found

```
FirstUnitWholeSalePrice.text
FirstUnitShopperPrice.text
FirstUnitDemotionsPrice.text
FirstUnitPriceDefault.text
SecondUnitWholeSalePrice.text
SecondUnitShopperPrice.text
SecondUnitDemotionsPrice.text
SecondUnitPriceDefault.text
ThirdUnitWholeSalePrice.text
ThirdUnitShopperPrice.text
ThirdUnitDemotionsPrice.text
ThirdUnitPriceDefault.text
DefaultPrice.text
```